# Windows Universal App with C# & CSS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, windows-phone, win-universal-app

Is it possible to write an universal app for windows where the logic is written in C# and the styling takes place in HTML and CSS like it is possible with Xamarin Hybrid Apps for Android/iOS?

So far I have only know of C# & XAML or Javascript & HTML/CSS. Either I have to rewrite all my styling in XAML or all my logic in javascript.

Comment: Self hosted web server with callbacks and the front-end in HTML/CSS, sure, but I'm not sure what you mean by "universal app"?

Comment: With "universal app" I mean the store apps that only need to be written once and should worke on normal PCs with Windows 8.1 and on WIndows Phone.

Comment: Yes you can use a hosted WebBrowser control inside a XAML app

Comment: Do you also know if there is the possibility to use the Razor Engine (from asp.net) to make it even more compatible with the Xamarin Hybrid Apps?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Razor but if it is a server-side technology then you should just be able to load the web pages inside the `WebBrowser` control

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard about using Windows Runtime Components which should do what you are asking for?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441572.aspx

"By using the Windows Runtime, you can create components (essentially DLLs) in C++, C#, or Visual Basic, and call into them in a simple and natural way from a Windows Store app that's built by using JavaScript"